# BibLaTeX: Suppress comma after editor names

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to get my bibliography to my needs, and there is one comma which I don't know how to remove.

In entry [2] ('inbook') it is correct, but in entry [1] ('book' without author, just editor) there shouldn't be the comma.

[image]

It is really difficult for me to understand all the `biblatex` commands, so it would be great if someone could help me with this issue.

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@book{awv_stmk,
    editor = "{Hans Wurst}",
    title = "{Das Leben}"
}

@inbook{book2,
    author = "Hans Wurst",
    booktitle = "Das Leben",
    editor = "Biene Maja",
    title = "Artikel"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}


% Put editor string in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Like editor+others but without comma before editor string and dash checks
\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test \ifuseeditor and not test {\ifnameundef{editor}} }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

% Print editors before "in" title
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
  \usebibmacro{ineditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \clearname{editor}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: For `authoryear` style, you modify the `bbx:editor` macro to put in a space instead of a comma and space. Try adding this:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\addcomma\space}{\addspace}{}{}
```

You can also do an equivalent change for `bbx:translator`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it is working for me on sharelatex, but not in my full project on my pc. Therefore I will need more time next week finding out why, and then I can come back to here to give more feedback.

Comment: Okay it was my fault, because in my actual project I am using [style=authoryear], which somehow ignores the code from your answer. I am sorry that I didn't know i should have included this information in my Question! Do you also know, how I can reach my goal in this case?

Comment: For `authoryear` style you need to edit the `bbx:editor` macro instead of `editor+others`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it works :-) I also added the `style=authoryear` line to my question.

Comment: In current versions of `biblatex` this does not work any more since there is a dedicated `editortypedelim` now. `\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}` should do the same thing. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419595/35864