# Remove comma after editor name in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

It is perhaps a dirty hack, but I redefine the "editor" string in `biblatex` manually with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{nynorsk}{editor = {(styr\adddot)}}`, which will give me both the Norwegian word for "editor" and a parenthesis around the word.

With the parenthesis, though, I feel there's no need for the comma following the editor name. The same question has been asked before, but the [accepted solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358580/9077) doesn't change anything for me (see the MWE below).

My question is, how can I remove the comma after the editor name?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, sorting = nyt, language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO, backend = biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}{}{} % remove parenthesis around year in bibliography
    \xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}{\addcomma\space}{\addspace}{}{} % <- this doesn't change anything

\DefineBibliographyStrings{nynorsk}{editor = {(styr\adddot)}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{ordbogoverdetdanskesprog,
    TITLE = "Ordbog over det danske sprog",
    YEAR = "1919--56",
    EDITOR = "H. Juul-Jensen",
    LOCATION = "K{\o}benhavn",
    PUBLISHER = "Gyldendal"}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The punctuation between the editor name and the type string is controlled by the context-sensitive delimiter `editortypedelim`.

It is more idiomatic to add the parentheses around the editor type string with the field format `editortype`.

The MWE also redefines the counterparts for `translator.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend = biber,
  style = authoryear-comp,
  language = nynorsk, sortlocale = nn_NO]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{nynorsk}{editor = {styr\adddot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}
  {\printtext[parens]}
  {\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}
  {}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ordbogoverdetdanskesprog,
  title       = {Ordbog over det danske sprog},
  date        = {1919/1956},
  editor      = {H. Juul-Jensen},
  editora     = {Verner Dahlerup},
  editoratype = {founder},
  location    = {København},
  publisher   = {Gyldendalske boghandel. Nordisk forlag},
  volumes     = {28},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Juul-Jensen, H. (styr.). 1919–56. Ordbog over det danske sprog. København: Gyldendal.]

With `biblatex-ext` there is an easier way to get rid of the parentheses around the year, see [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864).