# Biblatex: Formatting @online and @incollection bibliographic entry types

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I'm trying to format two Biblatex entry types.

For the `@incollection` entry I want to get rid of the first comma (marked in yellow) and change the second comma to a period.

For the `@online` entry I can't seem to get rid of the date. Even if there is no date field in the entry, the brackets still show up but empty. I also want to change the comma after the title *'Polymer'* to a period. Is there a way to suppress the '*Adresse:*' (german for 'url:') string?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half, 
   BCOR=12mm, captions=tableheading, openany, numbers=noenddot, headinclude, 
   liststotoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@online{polymer2020,
    title = {Polymer},
    author = {{N. N.}},
    journaltitle = {Wikipedia},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer},
    urldate = {2020-02-16}
}
@incollection{hans2020,
    title = {Ein {{Qualit\"atsicherungskonzept}}},
    booktitle = {Additive {{Fertigung}} von {{Bauteilen}}},
    author = {Hans, Peter and Werner, Meier},
    editor = {Michael, Hauser},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {{Springer}},
    location = {{Berlin}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nyt, 
   autocite=inline, isbn=false, dashed=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{series}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*[online]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{polymer2020}
    \cite{hans2020}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic but still relevant: (a) The `@online` entry type doesn't process the `journaltitle` field type. I believe you should replace `journaltitle = {Wikipedia}` with `organization = {Wikipedia}`. (The field `journaltitle` should really only be used with entries of type `@article`.) (b) Unless you're obliged to stick to the pre-1995 
German language spelling and hyphenation rules, you should probably replace `\usepackage[german]{babel}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first comma in the `@incollection` you need to redefine `editortypedelim` (see for example [Remove comma after editor name in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511330/35864) and [biblatex: How to remove the comma before ed./eds.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30151/35864)).

The period is a bit tricker and in the example there are several ways to produce a period in that position, but the effects may vary if there are more fields in the entry. Here I decided to go via the bibmacro `publisher+location+date`.

The parentheses around the missing date can only be removed by patching the driver (cf. also [Remove parentheses for empty year field biblatex ieee style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151217/35864), though the solution presented here is slightly more elegant).

Again the period in the `@online` entry can be produced in several ways. Since we are patching the driver already, I decided to patch it in such a way to insert the period directly before the URL. Again the result can vary if more fields are present.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half, BCOR=12mm, captions=tableheading, openany, numbers=noenddot, headinclude, liststotoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nyt,
  autocite=inline, isbn=false, dashed=false, url=false]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*[online]{title}{\textit{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{series}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
  {\setunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
  {}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{polymer2020,
  title        = {Polymer},
  author       = {{N. N.}},
  journaltitle = {Wikipedia},
  url          = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer},
  urldate      = {2020-02-16},
}
@incollection{hans2020,
  title     = {Ein Qualitätsicherungskonzept},
  booktitle = {Additive Fertigung von Bauteilen},
  author    = {Hans, Peter and Werner, Meier},
  editor    = {Michael, Hauser},
  date      = {2020},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location  = {Berlin},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{polymer2020}
    \cite{hans2020}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hans, P.; Werner, M., Ein Qualitätsicherungskonzept, in Additive Fertigung von Bauteilen, Michael, H. (Hrsg.). Berlin: Springer, 2020.//N. N. Polymer. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer (besucht am 16.02.2020).]