# Remove undesired comma with group editor

Tags: biblatex

I have a question about the Editor Name in the bibliography.
The Name is "Koordinierungsgruppe der CE in der Katholischen Kirche". The problem is that `biblatex` doesn't recognize it as one name but as the last name. So in the bibliography it always prints "Koordinierungsgruppe der CE in der Katholischen Kirche,". How is it possible to remove the comma? I already tried with extra `{}` but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
%%%
%Biblatex-Einstellungen
%%%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic, style=authortitle-ibid, pagetracker=false]{biblatex}
%%%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%Hg statt Hrsg.
editor ={\addspace\nopunct\mkbibparens{Hg\adddot}},
}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}%Doppelpunkt nach Autor beim Zitieren
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}%Title nicht kursiv
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Kapitälchen Nachnahme
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Kapitälchen Vornahme
%%%
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@booklet{Geistmachtlebendig,
editor = {{Koordinierungsgruppe der CE in der Katholischen Kirche}},
title = {Der Geist macht lebendig}, 
year = {2007},
subtitle = {Theologische und pastorale Grundlagen der charismatischen Erneuerung in der katholischen Kirche Deutschlands}
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%
\bibliography{literatur}
\begin{document}
Text \footcite{Geistmachtlebendig}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx,

Comment: Very nice code example for a first question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the way you enter "corporate"/"institutional"/group authors (which you already do correctly in your MWE, namely with curly braces, see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864) for reference).

The problem is the way you add parentheses around the "Hrsg.". Cite `westfahl:frontier` from `biblatex-examples.bib` to see that the exact same issue also occurs with a normal name (with family and given part). The best way to add parentheses around "Hsrg." is change the `editortype` field format. Then you additionally need to modify `editortypedelim` to print only a space and not a comma. (See, e.g. [Remove comma after editor name in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511330/35864) or [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419595/35864) to [biblatex: How to remove the comma before ed./eds.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30151/35864.))

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authortitle-ibid, pagetracker=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hg\adddot},
  editors = {Hgg\adddot},
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{Geistmachtlebendig,
  editor   = {{Koordinierungsgruppe der CE in der Katholischen Kirche}},
  title    = {Der Geist macht lebendig}, 
  year     = {2007},
  subtitle = {Theologische und pastorale Grundlagen
              der charismatischen Erneuerung
              in der katholischen Kirche Deutschlands},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text \footcite{Geistmachtlebendig,westfahl:frontier}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Koordinierungsgruppe der CE in der Katholischen Kirche (Hg.): Der Geist macht lebendig. Theologische und pastorale Grundlagen der charismatischen Erneuerung in der katholischen Kirche Deutschlands. 2007.]

- Unless you have a compelling reason to stick to BibTeX (`backend=bibtex,`) I would suggest you look into using Biber. Usually that is as easy as changing `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and running Biber instead of BibTeX (many people have their editor run these programs, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help). Only Biber supports all of `biblatex`'s features. In particular only Biber fully supports Unicode and Unicode sorting.
- In the example `bibstyle=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic, style=authortitle-ibid,` is completely equivalent to just `style=authortitle-ibid,`, but the latter is arguably much easier to understand (and much shorter).
- `\labelnamepunct` is deprecated and replaced by the context-sensitive delimiter `nametitledelim`.
- Instead of redefining `\mkbibnamelast` and `\mkbibnamefirst` (which were deprecated in favour of `\mkbibnamefamily` and `\mkbibnamegiven`, respectively, more than five years ago) separately, just redefine `\mkbibcompletename`. (Cite `von Brandt, Ahasver` to see the difference).
- The `csquotes` option `babel` was renamed to `autostyle` more than eleven years ago.