# Editing bibstyle (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to perfect my bibliography and I have a small issue with the bibstyle I'm using. Bear in mind that I searched for ages to find something that matched my expectations even to this degree, so I don't really want answers that tell me to just search for a new precoded style altogether. So I'm using the style `trad-abbrv` that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo). My problem is with the entry type `incollection`, where it just seperates the word 'editors' with a comma. I would love for it to look exactly the same, only the word 'editors' is in brackets (see example below). Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=trad-abbrv]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

This is the reference \cite{ref}.\medskip

How I would like it to look:

A. Author and B. Buthor. Title. In E. Editor and F. Fditor (editors) \textit{Booktitle}, pages 50-100. Publisher, 2021\medskip

How it actually looks:
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard styles have `editortype` and `editortypedelim` for that (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419595/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173778/35864), but `biblatex-trad` has its own macros for this job that we need to modify

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=trad-abbrv]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editorlstr}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{editorlstr}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
      or
      test {\ifandothers{editor}}
    }%
      {\biblstring{editors}}%
      {\biblstring{editor}}}}

\begin{document}
This is the reference \cite{westfahl:space,brandt,pines}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: S. Pines. The limitations of human knowledge according to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and Maimonides. In I. Twersky (editor) Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature, pages 82–109. Harvard University Press, Cambridge, Mass., 1979.]

Comment: Thank you so much! Seeing it in my thesis like this I would actually love to add another little change: Is it possible to have the word editors abbreviated? I'm writing in German though, so it would have to work in German as well.

Comment: @Lilo **Either** change the two `\biblstring`s in `\renewbibmacro*{editorlstr}` above to `\bibstring` and load the style with the option `abbreviate = true,` **or** change the two `\biblstring`s in `\renewbibmacro*{editorlstr}` above to `\bibsstring`. The first approach will also influence other bits of the style and will generally abbreviate other strings as well, the second approach only makes this instance of "editors" short. This works for all languages supported by `biblatex` (provided they define a short form different from the long from), so in particular also for German.